# Matlab: ODE45+Shooting Method appear to be not working

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, differential-equations, runge-kutta, ode45

I am trying to solve numerically three simultaneous ODE functions:

```
dw/ds = sin(theta)

dx1/ds = cos(theta)

dtheta/ds = - a * cos(theta) * (w-w0) + a * sin(theta) * x1
```

I am solving for a column which is separated in two halves, I want to plot w against x1 and have a positive w (something that is seeming to be impossible right now). There are three main functions:

- first_sec_w: the one that is using RK4 method with the already found out initial value for theta (using shoot_first and shoot_second).
- shoot_first: a function that solves the function using RK4 assuming initial values for theta until the boundary condition of 0 at L0/2 is achieved and return this initial value.
- shoot_second: pretty much does the same thing as the above, but it starts from L0 and goes until L0/2.

Can anyone help me out?

I will upload the codes so here it does not appear too messy.

[RK.zip](http://download1337.mediafire.com/py4gttyj0bjg/r135aji12ceh65n/RK.rar)

Comment: dan, what is the problem?

Comment: I am getting weird plots, it seems that my initial guesses for the shooting method are not alright. Do you any way to do the initial value guesses knowing a boundary value (in my case w'(L0/2)=0 )?